# How to tell screen resolution in "DP"?

Tags: android

I am working on an application based on Galaxy S at the moment. I know that Galaxy S is 480 px wide and 800 px tall, but how much is that in DP?

Lets say if I want to have two Layout side by side, I'll have them setting to 240 px. But how do I know what value I should use in DP unit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The conversion of dip units to screen pixels is simple: pixels = dips * (density / 160). For example, on 240 dpi screen, 1 dip would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dip units to define your application's UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens.

Found: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[edit]
I just had to used this. Using the `DisplayMetrics.density` returns only 0.75, 1 and 1.5. Use `DisplayMetrics.densityDpi` instead or change the math to `pixels = dips * DisplayMetrics.density`

Comment: How did I missed that! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that `DP` is a not about resolution at all, it's about screen size because it's based on 160dpi baseline. An easy way to calculate will be: `ScreenSizeInInches` * 160.

In your case:

Width in Inches = `480px/(240px/inch)` = `2 inches` 
Height in Inches = `800px/(240px/inch)` = `10/3 inches`

Check: `sqrt(sqr(2) + sqr(10/3))` ~= `4 inches` which is the size of a Galaxy S.

So the size in dp is `(2 * 160) x (10/3 * 160)` = `320dp x 533.3dp`